# How to bulk test the Sagemaker Object detection model with a .mat dataset or S3 folder of images?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mat, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained the following Sagemaker model: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/introduction_to_amazon_algorithms/object_detection_pascalvoc_coco

I've tried both the JSON and RecordIO version. In both, the algorithm is tested on ONE sample image. However, I have a dataset of 2000 pictures, which I would like to test. I have saved the 2000 jpg pictures in a folder within an S3 bucket and I also have two .mat files (pics + ground truth). How can I apply this model to all 2000 pictures at once and then save the results, rather than doing it one picture at a time?

I am using the code below to load a single picture from my S3 bucket:

```
object = bucket.Object('pictures/pic1.jpg')
object.download_file('pic1.jpg')
img=mpimg.imread('pic1.jpg')
img_name = 'pic1.jpg'
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show(imgplot)

with open(img_name, 'rb') as image:
    f = image.read()
    b = bytearray(f)
    ne = open('n.txt','wb')
    ne.write(b)

import json
object_detector.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
results = object_detector.predict(b)
detections = json.loads(results)
print (detections['prediction'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. However, if you want to feed multiple images to the model at once, you can create a multi-dimensional array of images (byte arrays) to feed the model.

The code would look something like this.

```
import numpy as np
...

#  predict_images_list is a Python list of byte arrays
predict_images = np.stack(predict_images_list)

with graph.as_default():
    #  results is an list of typical results you'd get.
    results = object_detector.predict(predict_images)
```

But, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to feed 2000 images at once. Better to batch them in 20-30 images at a time and predict.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!